# Error al subir una página al servidor

Tags: html5, servidor

Llevo varios días subiendo mi carpeta `public_html` a un servidor por Filezilla pero no me cargan las imágenes ni los scripts. Conozco los directorios Raíz, quizás tengo fallos en la URL, pero he intentado con URLs relativas y absolutas y siguen sin cargarse.

¿Será cuestión del servidor?

He intentado con:

```
<img class="marca_logo" src="ftp://carlos%2540trideagency.com@ftp.trideagency.com/TR%21IDE/public_html/images/marca.png" width="170" height="60" alt="marca"/>
<img class="marca_logoMenu" src="ftp://carlos%2540trideagency.com@ftp.trideagency.com/TR%21IDE/public_html/images/marca_menu.png" width="110" height="110" alt="marca_menu"/>   

<img class="marca_logo" src="ftp://carlos%2540trideagency.com@ftp.trideagency.com/TR%21IDE/public_html/images/marca.png" width="170" height="60" alt="marca"/>

<img class="marca_logoMenu" src="ftp://carlos%2540trideagency.com@ftp.trideagency.com/TR%21IDE/public_html/images/marca_menu.png" width="110" height="110" alt="marca_menu"/>

 src="/vendor/parallax.js"></script>
 <!-- App JS -->
 <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

En unas uso la que se suele usar, que es /, para que tome como referencia desde el raíz que es el `index.html`, pero con ninguna ruta me cargan las cosas en el servidor.

[image: Esos son los directorios]

Comment: Hiciste la prueba con `src="../images/marca_menu.png"` por ejemplo para cargar una imagen.

Comment: Si, de hecho hasta use esta src="ftp://carlos%2540trideagency.com@ftp.trideagency.com/TR%21IDE/public_html/images/Loading.gif" que me la da el servidor como tal, y la que mencione, y esa que me indicas.

Comment: Yo creo, que puede estar afectando que este dentro de un directorio la public_html, pero hice pruebas e igual no funciono

Comment: No entiendo porque los src de tus imagenes empiezan con `ftp://carlos%2540trideagency.com@ftp.trideagency.com/TR%21IDE/public_html/` si solo basta con `images/imagen.jpg`

Comment: Es que intente con esa URL que dices y tampoco me funciono, quizas sea el servidor